# render_to_string rails 3.1

Tags: render-to-string, rails-3.1

I try this:

> :content => render_to_string(:template => "#{path[:controller]}/#{path[:action]}.html.haml")

In my json, but I use kaminari to paginate pages and a receive this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial kaminari/paginator with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:json], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.

Anyone know how I solution this?